# Hiding certain DIVs (not nested unfortunately)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working with legacy code that is generated automatically and must comply to the following structure:

```
<div id="TITLE1"></div>
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
<div id="div-4"></div>
.... (there can be more divs here, IDs can vary as well) ...
<div id="TITLE2"></div>
```

What I want to do now is the following:

- Make `TITLE1` clickable
- Once clicked hide all underlying `DIVs` (not nested and not possible to nest)
- Another click on `TITLE1` shows the previously hidden `DIVs` again
- Only hide those `DIVs` that follow a `TITLE` up to a next `TITLE` (excluding)

The Solution may use jQuery or such frameworks.

Comment: Where do you run into trouble?

Comment: you want to do an accordian??

Comment: All DIVs are independent from one another. I do not want to call every div by name and hide as the number, ids can vary. I haven't really coded anything just yet, trying to think of a good flexible solution first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
$('div[id^=TITLE]').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('div[id^=TITLE]').toggle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tjc8Q/)

The underlying logic is simple - Make divs with id starting with `TITLE` clickable by adding a click handler - to do this [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector is used. Then find all divs between the clicked element and the next element with id starting with `TITLE` - this is done using [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) traversal method. Then [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used to hide/show the element

Comment: Write less, do more is really accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", 'div[id^="TITLE"]', function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('div[id^="TITLE"]').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cjZzG/

That is, whenever a div that has an `id` beginning with the text "TITLE" is clicked, use the [`.nextUntil()` method](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil) to select every element up to the next such div and then toggle their visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Would be much easier if you could wrap the `title1` and `div-#` elements in one div. Then you could detect a click on `title1`, grab the parent then hide all of the children but the title div.

Something like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="title">Toggle divs</div>
    <div id="div1">Div1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div2</div>
    <div id="div3">Div3</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="title">Toggle divs</div>
    <div id="div1">Div4</div>
    <div id="div2">Div5</div>
    <div id="div3">Div6</div>
</div>      

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.title').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().children().not('.title').toggle(1000); 
    });
});
```

That is the solution I would use as it groups the elements logically: better for SEO and readability of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/WBH7C/

However, if the HTML cannot be edited then a solution like this would have to suffice:

```
$('div[id^=TITLE]').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('div[id^=TITLE]').find('div[id^=div-]').toggle();
})
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Have you read my entire answer? `However, if the HTML cannot be edited then a solution like this would have to suffice:`

Comment: To work with the original html I think you'd need to remove the `.find('div[id^=div-]')` from the code at the end of your answer (because `.nextUntil()` will have already selected the divs you need, and then `.find()` won't find anything).